# Translucent Dialog Box in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

[image]

Hi, I wish to achieve this look for my alert dialog but is unsure of how should i do it. I do know how to get the transparent alert dialog look in android but I can't find any clue for it to be translucent. Please leave some opinion or guide on how should I start doing it. Thanks so much!

Update:
Sorry I have forgotten to include that actually I am using xml with the alert dialog theme instead of the normal alert dialog.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To see the underlying activity un-dimmed:

```
dialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
```

To have the Dialog's background translucent, you have to set a background color with alpha < 255 (see the `Color` API).

Comment: Actually I'm using xml with alert dialog theme rather than inflating the alert dialog as normal. Have tried the above code and errors appears. Guess that only work for the inflated alert dialog. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Ok, what errors appear (edit your post). Secondly, you can inherit the alert dialog theme to set the background color in xml as well.

Answer (score 3):

you can creat custom dialog and refer it to style :

```
 final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context,R.style.cust_dialog);
```

then create xml in values folder named dialog_style.xml :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>   
   <style name="cust_dialog"> 
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item> 
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent_color</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item> 
    <item name="android:textSize">30dp</item>
   <item name="android:gravity">left</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

also create color.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>   
     <color name="transparent_color">#00000000</color>
  </resources>
```

by this you will get Translucent Dialog Box ,

and you can control the Translucency as you need.

hope help you.

Comment: i followed the codes given thank you, but it turned out transparent instead of translucent...

Answer (score 0):

add this line.

```
 dialog.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(0,0,0,0);
```